# How to get records same column name values in jdbc?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I had retrieved all records from db which have fields name,email,id,manager and I need to get all data records which have same manager and save it to list how can I to do it?

I had retrieved values from db has

```
 List<Map<String, String> dbData=new ArrayList<>();
while(query.next()){
 LinkedHashMap<String,String> rowData=new LinkedHashMal<>();
 for(columns=1;columns<total columns; columns++){
 rowData.put(columnNames,query.getString(columnNames.get(columns));
 }
 dbData.add(rowData);
}
```

Where columnNames is header list which contains all headers of the column.

So I need to get all records of same manager and export it to separate Excel file

Comment: *"which have same manager"* Do you mean that you want all records that have a *particular* manager, or that you want the data collected into groups of records that shared the same manager, e.g. a `Map<Manager, List<Record>>` kind of result?

Comment: Ya exactly same like that but I don't know how to achieve it

Comment: If it has same manager I want it as list

Comment: So, what should the list contain if you're not using a POJO model?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter by a certain manager you have to include the manager as a `WHERE` clause of your query. Something like:

```
SELECT name, email, id, manager FROM Table WHERE manager = 'manager1'
```

Once you have all records you wanted you can iterate through your `ResultSet` and add them too your list.

For more info you can check [this link](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0003)

Comment: In that case you should follow [Andreas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55125937/9092674)

Answer (score 0):

First, you read all the rows from the database into Java objects.

Assuming you read the data into a `List<Record>`, you can then group the data using Java 8 streams:

```
List<Record> rows = ...
Map<String, List<Record>> byManager = rows.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getManager, Collectors.toList()));
```

---

**UPDATE**

If the record is a `Map<String, String>` mapping column name to stringified value, the code would be:

```
List<Map<String, String>> rows = ...
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> byManager = rows.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(row -> row.get("manager"), Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I am not using pojo model

Comment: @user10506901 Don't know what you mean by *"not using pojo model"*. Question says *"I need to get all data records [...] and save it to list"*. To store records in a list, you need some class to hold the record data. Whether that class is a POJO or not doesn't matter.

Comment: I had retrieved values as key and value pair using map and I am stuck how to group the record if it has same manager and I am not using pojo because it is dynamic say, if I add new column in db then I need to change pojo class

Comment: @user10506901 So you have read the data into a `List<Map<String, Object>>` or `List<Map<String, String>>`, or something like that? Please, just **edit** the question and show what you've done already, so we can stop wasting time trying to guess.